# Image is not shown over the entire screen despite css code

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

On my website, I want to cover a page (not the home page) completely with a picture. It should completely fill the screen on every device. I have specially created a childtheme to handle this problem.

On my website, I want to create a gallery facility that greets the visitor with a picture across the entire screen. I've created a childtheme for it as already mentioned. I first tried once in the `functions.php` folder to set the content width to 100%. Unfortunately, this did not work. Then I tried it with all over the custom css field on my wordpress theme. That too did not work.

```css
`element.style {
background-image: url(https://philippfalkenhagen.de/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Reh-im-Mohnfeld-Startseite-1.jpg);
max-width: 100%;
height: 801px;
width: 100%;
}
```

With this code, it should actually be funkitoinieren as I want. Unfortunately I can not integrate it into my data. He does not fit in `functions.php` and he does not work as a custom css either.

`// set default content width
if ( ! isset( $content_width ) ) {
    $content_width = 680;
}`

This code in the `functions.php` folder was my second attempt. I could not set the width to 100% and on all other values ​​she looked the same.

I expect that the picture under philippfalkenhagen.de/tiere-2`fills the entire screen. unfortunately it is not like that. When I used 100% of the second code, I could not even access my website until I reset the code.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dealing with a background and not a figure itself, try to use `background-size: 100% 100%` and `background-repeat: no-repeat`.

```css
`element.style {
background-image: url(https://philippfalkenhagen.de/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Reh-im-Mohnfeld-Startseite-1.jpg);
max-width: 100%;
height: 801px;
width: 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Comment: Alternatively use `background-size: cover;` to scale and crop the image to fully cover the element regardless of the aspect ratio of the element or image.

Answer (score 0):

```
background-size: cover;
```

will help you to solve this issue.

updated:

```
`element.style {
   background-image: url(https://philippfalkenhagen.de/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Reh-im-Mohnfeld-Startseite-1.jpg);
   max-width: 100%;
   height: 801px;
   width: 100%;
   background-size: cover; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I do not know exactly where to insert the code. Can you help me there?

Answer (score 0):

This is my functions.php folder:

```
https://we.tl /t-g7Mvc2EbC6
```

I suspect that I have to put the code here, but I do not know where.